# Unable to merge dex after Android Studio Upgrade to 3.0

Tags: android-studio-3.0

Did anyone manage to solve  this

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
>   dex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue, it worked out for me

1. Clean
    &
2. Rebuild